# Will this urllib2 python code download the page of the file?

Tags: python, http, urllib2

**urllib2.urlopen(theurl).read()** ...this downloads the file.

**urllib2.urlopen(theurl).geturl()**...does this download the file? (how long does it take)

Comment: For the record, since my answer is not entirely correct I think you should switch the accepted answer from mine to RichieHindle's. I tried to delete it but won't let me delete an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not.
For me, a test on google.com:

```
x= time.time(); urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read(); print time.time()-x
0.166881084442

x= time.time(); urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").geturl(); print time.time()-x
0.0772399902344
```

Comment: This answer arguably wrong, because `geturl()` *does* download (some of) the file. The way to test whether it downloads the file is to look at the network traffic with something like Wireshark, not to use a timer.  If the question is "does `geturl()` download the entire file even if it's very big?" then the answer is "No", fair enough.  But it's not as clear-cut as this answer makes out, and using a timer to infer what's happening on the network is unreliable.

Comment: I see. My apologies for not delving deeply enough into this problem and providing a hasty answer. Another thing I should have done, in any case, is looped over the expressions and provided an averaged time estimate.

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#high-level-interface):

> The geturl() method returns the real
>   URL of the page. In some cases, the
>   HTTP server redirects a client to
>   another URL. The urlopen() function
>   handles this transparently, but in
>   some cases the caller needs to know
>   which URL the client was redirected
>   to. The geturl() method can be used to
>   get at this redirected URL.

Comment: That's all true, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Tested with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and Python 2.5: `urllib2.urlopen(theurl).geturl()` downloads *some* of the body.  It issues a `GET`, reads the header and a couple of K of the body, and then stops.

Comment: Yes, and this is because of redirects - I assume that urllib2 supports proper (http 301 / 302) redirects and "<meta refresh"-redirects. For real redirects, reading the header would be enough...

Comment: `geturl()` does not download anything, `urllib2.urlopen(theurl)` does.

Comment: @Lukáš Lalinský: And you tested that with a network monitoring tool, did you?  When I did that, I looked at the URL http://entrian.com/source-search and it certainly *did* download some of the content.

Comment: No, I looked at the source code. `geturl()` is defined as `return self.url`.

Comment: @Lukáš Lalinský: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your comment.  I thought you were saying that `urllib2.urlopen(theurl).geturl()` doesn't download anything.  I've clarified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

urllib2.urlopen() returns a file like object, so that when using urlopen() you are actually download the document, and it's loaded into your machine's memory, you can use file functions to read write your file, like so...

#to store python.org into your local file d:\python.org.html

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
doc = urlopen("http://www.python.org")
html=doc.read( )
f=open("d:/python.org.html","w+")
f.write(html)
f.close()
```

or simply using urllib

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.python.org","d:/python.org.html")
```

hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

No. geturl() returns the url.

For example; `urllib2.urlopen("http://www.python.org").geturl()` returns  the string 'http://www.python.org'.

You can find this sort of stuff really easily in the python interactive shell e.g;

```
$ python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jul 27 2009, 17:57:39)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> u = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.python.org")
>>> u.geturl()
'http://www.python.org'
>>>
```